# Animating multiple prototype tableview cells

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have two prototype cells in `myTableView`, namely `myTableViewCell` and `myHeaderCell`. I am using `willDisplay cell` method for animating as follows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let rotationTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, -500, 10, 0)
    cell.layer.transform = rotationTransform

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations : { () -> Void in
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    })
}
```

But only `myTableViewCell` is being animated but not `myHeaderCell`. How do I make both prototype cells animate at the same time?

I added the following code in willDisplayHeaderView method, but still did not work

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myHeaderCell") as! HeaderCell
    let rotationTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, -500, 10, 0)
    cell.layer.transform = rotationTransform
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations : {() -> Void in
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    })
}
```

Comment: `myHeaderCell` is a `headerView` or `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: I used viewForHeaderInSection method that returns UIView for myHeaderCell

Comment: Then use `func tableView(UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView: UIView, forSection: Int)` to apply the same animation.

Comment: @Kamran, I did apply animation as you told above, please see edited question. Am I missing anything as it is not getting animated?

Comment: Yes, remove this line `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myHeaderCell") as! HeaderCell`. And replace `cell` with `view`.
`

Comment: @Kamran, appreciate it for teaching me a new concept. That works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap up the animation code inside a method,

```
private func animate(view: UIView) {
   let rotationTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, -500, 10, 0)
    view.layer.transform = rotationTransform
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations : {() -> Void in
        view.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    })
}
```

And then you can just pass any view you want to apply this animation effect. For example in the above case you want to animate `cell` and `table` header so you just have to call the `animate` method on them.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.animate(view: cell)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
   self.animate(view: view)
}
```

Remember `UITableViewCell` and `TableView` header both are `UIView` so `animate` method will work as expected.

And never `deque...` any `cell` or `section` header inside `willDisplay` delegate method. As the name implies, cell/header is just going to display, its already created/dequed so you don't need to create it again.

Comment: This will simplify the process more rather than writing animation code in bothe cell and view. Appreciate your detailed explaination.

Comment: Yes, it will help apply the same animation on any other element. Also you may want to tweak the values `-500, 10` and `duration 1.0` in future so this will help to do it once. You can also enhance this by introducing more parameters in animate method with duration or translation values.

Comment: I will tweak those and play with them in future and experiment it with more parameters. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Is there a way we can call animate method in ViewWillAppear() for both cell and view?

Comment: No, `tableView` `willDisplay` for cell/header is similar to `viewWillAppear` for `ViewController` so it should from there or from any other delegate method of `UITableView` but not from the `viewWillAppear` of `ViewController`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

That should work. The only thing that I could think of is your `myHeaderCell` is not set as a cell for the section.

But a headerView / cell.

If you use `myHeaderCell` in here:

```
tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)
```

then you should also put your animation code in

```
tableView(_:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:)
```

the delegate method for header is different for cell.

EDIT: In your edited question, you don't need to dequeue anything. I'm surprised that didn't produced an error.

You already have the hold of the view header instance, through the delegate.

Directly use the view instance.

Comment: Please see edited question above, I did as you said, not animating. Am I missing anything now?

Comment: @Coder221 check my response.

Comment: Appreciate your explaination.